# How do i upload my LibGDX game online ?

Tags: java, html, wordpress, libgdx

I have a wordpress website and wish to upload my LibGDX game on to there

Any ideas how to do this ? Or know of a link to somewhere which would help ?

Thankyou

Comment: you can upload whatever you want onto your website.

Comment: i know but how would i upload my libgdx game to my wordpress website ? @MarcB

Comment: how should we know? presumably your wp site has an "attach a file" somewhere or whatever. you're basically saying "I've got a car. where do I drive it to?"

Comment: @MarcB A little more respect for the new guys please, they don't know all the rules yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this site http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/can-i-upload-games-to-blog, it appears you can't unless you have a specific type of WordPress account. Sorry mate.

EDIT - or if your game is a flash game or something of the like, just read the link, it'll explain it better

Comment: If you need help setting up a new website, perhaps I could help? @AaronJones

Comment: sorry for the late reply didnt know you commented. Cheers for the offer, appreciate it, but at the moment i havent got a lot of time to start from scratch :( tbh dont know why i didnt make my own website from scratch when i started :(